# How do I use big ints in eos?

Tags: smart-contract, library, integer

Is there a library that will let me store big ints and then perform arithmetic on them in eos smart contracts? I was trying to use the multiprecision library in boost but kept on getting an error: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4350

Performing arithmetic on the provided `checksum256` type is not so easy as it is just an array of smaller ints.

Comment: How big of integers are you looking for?  The smart contracts support `uint128_t` natively.

Comment: @JohnHaager 256 bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a [big integer library](https://github.com/plactal/biginteger-for-eosio) for EOS.IO made by PlayerOne.

Comment: this library is quite outdated. I had to make quite a few changes to get it to compile. Seems to be working so far though.